# phpMQTT publish not working

Tags: php, android, mqtt, phpmqtt

I have installed [Mosquitto](http://mosquitto.org) on the server, and it's running, and working fine.
I have installed Paho mqtt client plugin to check.
and I wrote the code for android and it's working fine on the emulator.

now in my own computer everything works fine, I run the php code and my app in android receives the message and Paho client receives that message too.

but when I upload the file on the server and run it nothing happens, although the php code runs everything successfully, and publishes the message without any error.
and even the mosquitto's publisher executable works fine and clients receive the message.

only this php code on the server doesn't do anything.

```
$mqtt = new phpMQTT("localhost", 1883, "server"); 

        if ($mqtt->connect()) {
            echo"connected\n";
            for($i=0;$i<4;++$i){

                if($mqtt->publish("new","Hey . ".$i,2)){
                    echo "published\n";
                }
                else{
                    echo "not published\n";
                }
            }
            $mqtt->close();
        }
        else{
            echo"couldn't connect\n";
        }
```

[Bluerhinos phpMQTT](https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT):

```
<?php
/* phpMQTT */
class phpMQTT {

    private $socket;            /* holds the socket */
    private $msgid = 1;         /* counter for message id */
    public $keepalive = 10;     /* default keepalive timmer */
    public $timesinceping;      /* host unix time, used to detect disconects */
    public $topics = array();   /* used to store currently subscribed topics */
    public $debug = true;       /* should output debug messages */
    public $address;            /* broker address */
    public $port;               /* broker port */
    public $clientid;           /* client id sent to brocker */
    public $will;               /* stores the will of the client */
    private $username;          /* stores username */
    private $password;          /* stores password */

    function __construct($address, $port, $clientid){
        $this->broker($address, $port, $clientid);
    }

    /* sets the broker details */
    function broker($address, $port, $clientid){
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->clientid = $clientid;        
    }

    /* connects to the broker 
        inputs: $clean: should the client send a clean session flag */
    function connect($clean = true, $will = NULL, $username = NULL, $password = NULL){

        if($will) $this->will = $will;
        if($username) $this->username = $username;
        if($password) $this->password = $password;

        $address = $this->address;  
        $this->socket = fsockopen($address, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, 60);

        if (!$this->socket ) {
            error_log("fsockopen() $errno, $errstr \n");
            return false;
        }

        stream_set_timeout($this->socket, 5);
        stream_set_blocking($this->socket, 0);

        $i = 0;
        $buffer = "";

        $buffer .= chr(0x00); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x06); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x4d); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x51); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x49); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x73); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x64); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x70); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr(0x03); $i++;

        //No Will
        $var = 0;
        if($clean) $var+=2;

        //Add will info to header
        if($this->will != NULL){
            $var += 4; // Set will flag
            $var += ($this->will['qos'] << 3); //Set will qos
            if($this->will['retain'])   $var += 32; //Set will retain
        }

        if($this->username != NULL) $var += 128;    //Add username to header
        if($this->password != NULL) $var += 64; //Add password to header

        $buffer .= chr($var); $i++;

        //Keep alive
        $buffer .= chr($this->keepalive >> 8); $i++;
        $buffer .= chr($this->keepalive & 0xff); $i++;

        $buffer .= $this->strwritestring($this->clientid,$i);

        //Adding will to payload
        if($this->will != NULL){
            $buffer .= $this->strwritestring($this->will['topic'],$i);  
            $buffer .= $this->strwritestring($this->will['content'],$i);
        }

        if($this->username) $buffer .= $this->strwritestring($this->username,$i);
        if($this->password) $buffer .= $this->strwritestring($this->password,$i);

        $head = "  ";
        $head{0} = chr(0x10);
        $head{1} = chr($i);

        fwrite($this->socket, $head, 2);
        fwrite($this->socket,  $buffer);

        $string = $this->read(4);

        if(ord($string{0})>>4 == 2 && $string{3} == chr(0)){
            if($this->debug) echo "Connected to Broker\n"; 
        }else{  
            error_log(sprintf("Connection failed! (Error: 0x%02x 0x%02x)\n", 
                                    ord($string{0}),ord($string{3})));
            return false;
        }

        $this->timesinceping = time();

        return true;
    }

    /* read: reads in so many bytes */
    function read($int = 8192, $nb = false){

        //  print_r(socket_get_status($this->socket));

        $string="";
        $togo = $int;

        if($nb){
            return fread($this->socket, $togo);
        }

        while (!feof($this->socket) && $togo>0) {
            $fread = fread($this->socket, $togo);
            $string .= $fread;
            $togo = $int - strlen($string);
        }




            return $string;
    }

    /* subscribe: subscribes to topics */
    function subscribe($topics, $qos = 0){
        $i = 0;
        $buffer = "";
        $id = $this->msgid;
        $buffer .= chr($id >> 8);  $i++;
        $buffer .= chr($id % 256);  $i++;

        foreach($topics as $key => $topic){
            $buffer .= $this->strwritestring($key,$i);
            $buffer .= chr($topic["qos"]);  $i++;
            $this->topics[$key] = $topic; 
        }

        $cmd = 0x80;
        //$qos
        $cmd += ($qos << 1);


        $head = chr($cmd);
        $head .= chr($i);

        fwrite($this->socket, $head, 2);
        fwrite($this->socket, $buffer, $i);
        $string = $this->read(2);

        $bytes = ord(substr($string,1,1));
        $string = $this->read($bytes);
    }

    /* ping: sends a keep alive ping */
    function ping(){
            $head = " ";
            $head = chr(0xc0);      
            $head .= chr(0x00);
            fwrite($this->socket, $head, 2);
            if($this->debug) echo "ping sent\n";
    }

    /* disconnect: sends a proper disconect cmd */
    function disconnect(){
            $head = " ";
            $head{0} = chr(0xe0);       
            $head{1} = chr(0x00);
            fwrite($this->socket, $head, 2);
    }

    /* close: sends a proper disconect, then closes the socket */
    function close(){
        $this->disconnect();
        fclose($this->socket);  
    }

    /* publish: publishes $content on a $topic */
    function publish($topic, $content, $qos = 0, $retain = 0){

        $i = 0;
        $buffer = "";

        $buffer .= $this->strwritestring($topic,$i);

        //$buffer .= $this->strwritestring($content,$i);

        if($qos){
            $id = $this->msgid++;
            $buffer .= chr($id >> 8);  $i++;
            $buffer .= chr($id % 256);  $i++;
        }

        $buffer .= $content;
        $i+=strlen($content);


        $head = " ";
        $cmd = 0x30;
        if($qos) $cmd += $qos << 1;
        if($retain) $cmd += 1;

        $head{0} = chr($cmd);       
        $head .= $this->setmsglength($i);

        if((fwrite($this->socket, $head, strlen($head)))&&(fwrite($this->socket, $buffer, $i))){
            echo "done: ".$this->socket."<br>";
            return true;
        }
        else {
            echo $head;
            return false;
        }

    }

    /* message: processes a recieved topic */
    function message($msg){
            $tlen = (ord($msg{0})<<8) + ord($msg{1});
            $topic = substr($msg,2,$tlen);
            $msg = substr($msg,($tlen+2));
            $found = 0;
            foreach($this->topics as $key=>$top){
                if( preg_match("/^".str_replace("#",".*",
                        str_replace("+","[^\/]*",
                            str_replace("/","\/",
                                str_replace("$",'\$',
                                    $key))))."$/",$topic) ){
                    if(function_exists($top['function'])){
                        call_user_func($top['function'],$topic,$msg);
                        $found = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if($this->debug && !$found) echo "msg recieved but no match in subscriptions\n";
    }

    /* proc: the processing loop for an "allways on" client 
        set true when you are doing other stuff in the loop good for watching something else at the same time */    
    function proc( $loop = true){

        if(1){
            $sockets = array($this->socket);
            $w = $e = NULL;
            $cmd = 0;

                //$byte = fgetc($this->socket);
            if(feof($this->socket)){
                if($this->debug) echo "eof receive going to reconnect for good measure\n";
                fclose($this->socket);
                $this->connect(false);
                if(count($this->topics))
                    $this->subscribe($this->topics);    
            }

            $byte = $this->read(1, true);

            if(!strlen($byte)){
                if($loop){
                    usleep(100000);
                }

            }else{ 

                $cmd = (int)(ord($byte)/16);
                if($this->debug) echo "Recevid: $cmd\n";

                $multiplier = 1; 
                $value = 0;
                do{
                    $digit = ord($this->read(1));
                    $value += ($digit & 127) * $multiplier; 
                    $multiplier *= 128;
                    }while (($digit & 128) != 0);

                if($this->debug) echo "Fetching: $value\n";

                if($value)
                    $string = $this->read($value,"fetch");

                if($cmd){
                    switch($cmd){
                        case 3:
                            $this->message($string);
                        break;
                    }

                    $this->timesinceping = time();
                }
            }

            if($this->timesinceping < (time() - $this->keepalive )){
                if($this->debug) echo "not found something so ping\n";
                $this->ping();  
            }


            if($this->timesinceping<(time()-($this->keepalive*2))){
                if($this->debug) echo "not seen a package in a while, disconnecting\n";
                fclose($this->socket);
                $this->connect(false);
                if(count($this->topics))
                    $this->subscribe($this->topics);
            }

        }
        return 1;
    }

    /* getmsglength: */
    function getmsglength(&$msg, &$i){

        $multiplier = 1; 
        $value = 0 ;
        do{
          $digit = ord($msg{$i});
          $value += ($digit & 127) * $multiplier; 
          $multiplier *= 128;
          $i++;
        }while (($digit & 128) != 0);

        return $value;
    }


    /* setmsglength: */
    function setmsglength($len){
        $string = "";
        do{
          $digit = $len % 128;
          $len = $len >> 7;
          // if there are more digits to encode, set the top bit of this digit
          if ( $len > 0 )
            $digit = ($digit | 0x80);
          $string .= chr($digit);
        }while ( $len > 0 );
        return $string;
    }

    /* strwritestring: writes a string to a buffer */
    function strwritestring($str, &$i){
        $ret = " ";
        $len = strlen($str);
        $msb = $len >> 8;
        $lsb = $len % 256;
        $ret = chr($msb);
        $ret .= chr($lsb);
        $ret .= $str;
        $i += ($len+2);
        return $ret;
    }

    function printstr($string){
        $strlen = strlen($string);
            for($j=0;$j<$strlen;$j++){
                $num = ord($string{$j});
                if($num > 31) 
                    $chr = $string{$j}; else $chr = " ";
                printf("%4d: %08b : 0x%02x : %s \n",$j,$num,$num,$chr);
            }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this library publish example and see what happens both logs: the localhost broker and the php log

https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT/blob/master/examples/publish.php

Comment: thanks for the reply, I found out that MQTT is limited to 1024 connections on a single port, so I moved to AMQP, it's way much better.

Comment: Well this could be a limit from default broker setup in Mosquitto, but it's not an MQTT protocol limit by itself:
https://twitter.com/saradhix/status/28025989189

Also you can try other scalable brokers like: ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ or HiveMQ.